# vim indentation after adding newline

Tags: vim

I'm searching for "& DEBUG_OP," and adding a newline

```
Before:

DEBUG_LOG(debug & DEBUG_OP,"entry is not found in %x", arg)

After:
DEBUG_LOG(debug & DEBUG_OP,
"entry is not found in %x", arg)

Expected:
 DEBUG_LOG(debug & DEBUG_OP,
            "entry is not found in %x", arg)
```

How do I indent the code after adding newline? The spaces needed to indent vary depending on where the DEBUG_LOG line is in the code. This is C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I press ESC and == in this case to trigger auto indent.